Citation-JS not using the specified CSL template
This question is about the JavaScript library [{citation.js}](https://citation.js.org/). I need to be able to generate in-text citations in various formats. For example:
AMA

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry (Loomes et al., 2017; Mantzalas et al, 2022).

APA

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry 1-2.

Although Cite.format allows you to specify a template, it doesn't seem to use it. My sample code shows me specifying different template values and obtaining the same generic result.
I assume that means that it uses code from {citeproc-js}. Citation-JS has plugins. Is one of them used for formatting the citations via CSL? I can't find any examples.
There is a tutorial for Outputs, but it contains almost no information.


        const Cite = require('citation-js');

        // Sample BibTeX string for demonstration
        const bibtex = `
        @article{Loomes2017,
            title = {Loomes Title},
            author = {Loomes, Rachel and Hull, Laura and Mandy, William Polmear Locke},
            date = {2017-06},
            journaltitle = {Journal of the American Academy of Child and Adolescent Psychiatry},
            volume = {56},
            number = {6},
            pages = {466--474},
            doi = {10.1016/j.jaac.2017.03.013}
        }
        @article{Mantzalas2022,
            title = {Mantzalas Title},
            author = {Mantzalas, Jane and Richdale, Amanda L. and Adikari, Achini and Lowe, Jennifer and Dissanayake, Cheryl},
            date = {2022-03},
            journaltitle = {Autism in Adulthood},
            volume = {4},
            number = {1},
            pages = {52--65},
            doi = {10.1089/aut.2021.0021}
        }
        `;

        // Create the citation-js object
        const library = new Cite(bibtex);

        let single_citation = "Loomes2017";
        let double_citation = "Loomes2017,Mantzalas2022";

        let single_inline_apa = library.format('citation', {
            entry: single_citation,
            format: 'html',
            template: "apa",
            lang: 'en-US'
        });

        console.log(`single inline APA: ${single_inline_apa}`);

        let double_inline_apa = 
            double_citation
            .split(",")
            .map(x => x.trim())
            .map(x => library.format('citation', {
                entry: x,
                format: 'html',
                template: "apa",
                lang: 'en-US'
                })
            )
            .join(",")

        console.log(`double inline APA: ${double_inline_apa}`);

        let single_inline_ama = library.format('citation', {
            entry: single_citation,
            format: 'html',
            template: "apa",
            lang: 'en-US'
        });

        console.log(`single inline AMA: ${single_inline_ama}`);

        let double_inline_ama = 
            double_citation
            .split(",")
            .map(x => x.trim())
            .map(x => library.format('citation', {
                entry: x,
                format: 'html',
                template: "ama",
                lang: 'en-US'
                })
            )
            .join(",")

        console.log(`double inline AMA: ${double_inline_ama}`);
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Citation-JS Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/citation-js/0.7.14/citation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>




Only a few citation styles are included in @citation-js/plugin-csl by default. To use the AMA style, you need to download and register it:
let style_ama = Cite.util.fetchFile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/citation-style-language/styles/master/american-medical-association.csl')
Cite.plugins.config.get('@csl').templates.add('ama', style_ama)

See also a different iteration of this question on GitHub: https://github.com/citation-js/citation-js/issues/231#issuecomment-2282724819.
